# Create a modal javafx.stage.FileChooser inside a swing application

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8

I have a Swing application the main window of which inherits `JFrame` class. This app is on transition to JavaFX so there is a lot on JavaFX components including control panels.
 I need to show native file chooser from non UI thread in modal way relatively to main `JFrame`.
This could be achieved by setting an owner of `FileChooser` class, but it requires `javafx.stage.Window` to be the owner.
Is there some hack to set `JFrame` as owner of javafx `FileChooser` or `Stage`?

Comment: none that I know of. 5 mins of googling shows that the common practice is to set the owner to `null`.

Comment: There is no problem to set an owner for window, the problem is that JFrame will be clickable when FileChooser is open.

Comment: you may want to consider adding the `swing` tag. The solution may be to disable selecting your JFrame somehow until the `FileChooser` closes, and I think programmers more experienced in `swing` may be more help than those with `javafx` experience in giving you a solution that does that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Somehow I missed this (now seems) obvious solution. Please provide it as an answer an I will mark it as one

Answer (score 2):

The solution may be to disable selecting your `JFrame` somehow until the `FileChooser` closes.

Here's some pseudocode, since I don't know swing all that well:

1. remove focus from the JFrame somehow (perhaps using `setFocusableWindowState(false)`?)
2. open the FileChooser on the FXApplication thread
3. after that finishes (done using `Thread.join()` or however you want to manage your threads), restore focus to the JFrame

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but to keep it precise I've added exact solution.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it was like just:

```
JFrame frame = // get window 
frame.setEnabled(false); // emulate window modality

    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (file == null || !openFile(file)) { // return true if file was opened correctly
        frame.setEnabled(true);
        frame.requestFocus(); // window looses focus after enabling
    }
```

So `FileChooser` will behave like modal window here. The downside is there's need to control all paths to enable window back so it will not stay disabled forever.

Comment: glad you got it to work! Be sure to click the checkbox to mark this answer as accepted, it helps people with the same issue in the future know they can find a solution here.